# Failed to populate a django3 database

Tags: django

I have an error, at the time of trying to save data in the database, the data is not saved, at the time of filling the data it seems that it saved the data but this does not do it, because each field is validated and when I send it not no error comes out this is the view which is class based.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import View

from .models import Comment

from .forms import CommentForm


class IndexView(View):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'home/index.html'
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.all().order_by('-pk')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        context['commentaries'] = self.get_queryset()
        context['form'] = self.form_class
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, self.get_context_data())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form.errors.as_json()
            return redirect('home:index')
```

and this is the form

```
from django import forms
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .models import Comment


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['name', 'comment']
        labels = {
            'name': 'Nombre',
            'comment': 'Comentario'
        }
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Ingrese su Nombre',
                    'id': 'name',
                }
            ),
            'comment': forms.Textarea(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Ingrese su comentario',
                    'id': 'comment',
                }
            )
        }
```

This is the model

```
from django.db import models


class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self):
        self.name = self.name.capitalize()
```

this is the html

```
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>{{ form.name.label }}</div>
                    <div>{{ form.name }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>{{ form.comment.label }}</div>
                    <div>{{ form.comment }}</div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Comentario</button>
            </form>
```

I already tried to put form.errors.as_json () to know what the error was but it doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `super` in your save method

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    self.name = self.name.capitalize()
    super().save(**kwargs)
```

The save method of the base class `models.Model` is what inserts the object into the database. By overriding it and not calling `super` you are preventing the object from being saved

Comment: thank you very much if it was the mistake I was trying to fix it a lot